# Can I boot from a .wim file on a usb?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10

The wim file on the usb has a Windows 10 image. Currently I'm using a Windows 8 Dell Venue 10 tablet. I've tried googling for help but nothing has worked. The USB doesn't show up in the boot setup.

Would booting from a .wim file even be possible?

Comment: It might help if you attempt to explain what problem you are trying to solved by booting to a .wim file.  It is worth pointing out, there is more to booting to .wim, then just supplying a .wim file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to download the Win 7 USB creator from here http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool (Microsoft Tool) and create a bootable USB key.

Rename your current WIM file to install.wim then replace the install.wim file on the USB key, sorry can't remember exactly where it is at this time.

Comment: the Win 7 USB creator works on windows 10 ;)

Comment: So does the Media Creation Tool, much easier to use it, then a legacy tool.

Comment: I might be a little bit late but this worked

Comment: deadlink, the new tool seems to asks for an ISO file

Comment: new link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool